# Visual studio custom class template with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In my WPF MVVM applications I use a lot of the same master detail classes which can have an Add, Edit, Delete, Save and Undo command.
So these class structures are quite the same everytime.

I know I can make class templates, but is there a possibiliy to make a class template which can have checkboxes where I can choose if I have to insert an Add and Save command in the class? And when I click OK, only the selected will show in my generated class.

Comment: Looks like an [N-tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384398.aspx) application.